# Drop Down selected value changed

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two `input` `radio` `buttons`

Here's the `HTML`:

```
 <div class="col-md-5 padding-Zero">
        <select name="fifthtype" class="dropdown" id="fifthtype" onChange="javascript:secondsChanged()">
        <option value="normal">Normal Second Mortgage</option>
        <option value="silent">1st-time Home Buyer Silent Second</option>
         </select>
 </div>
```

these two `dropdown` `options` have two different values each

```
 <label id="Label19"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["normalsecond"],2)?></label>



<label id="Label19"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["silentsecond"],2)?></label>
```

Now my question is, I want to show my value  if I select *Normal Second Mortgage*, I want to show its value as:

```
<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["normalsecond"],2)?>
```

and vice-versa for this:

```
<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["silentsecond"],2)?>
```

How I will do this? added jsfiddle  in my code ? please take look this https://jsfiddle.net/kdt33vo6/

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated the IDs for label element. IDs must be unique. you can rather add same classname.

You can use index of selected option element to target label elements in change event of select:

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('.pull-right').hide().eq($(this).find('option:selected').index()).show()
}).change();//for showing changes on load
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuodhzjm/)**

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: @Millind Anantwar  ok sure

Comment: not Working @Milind Anantwar. both are different page  drop down option code  contain home page  and label  box contain result page.

Comment: i am lost now. as per the code given by you its working now in fiddle.

Comment: i have Two page  option code in home page and label code in results page @Milind Anantwar

Comment: values not showing your code  your code hide all fields@Milind Anantwar

Comment: you can make selector more specific. to only target those two label elements. like `$('#SecondMortgage .pull-right')`

Comment: fields is showed   but value i give 34  now looks like       $34 $0  showing like this .   sorry i give trouble to u

Comment: @sumathiN: hey. don't say sorry.. that's totally fine. glad i could help you. can you share the part that you are referring to.

Comment: @sumathiN: again. you have not modifies the label ids. i cannot help you this way unless you put effort to do the changes.

Comment: i need to change label id  two label

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over your markup then you can make use of `data-*` html5 attribute:

```
<option value="normal" data-target="second">Normal Second Mortgage</option>
<option value="silent" data-target="first">1st-time Home Buyer Silent Second</option>
```

then in the `label`s :

remove the ids because you are applying same ids to different elements.

```
<label class="pull-right first">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["normalsecond"],2)?></label>
<label class="pull-right second">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["silentsecond"],2)?></label>
```

add those target attribute to class names then you can use this js code:

```
$('#fifthtype').change(function(){
    var lbl = $(':selected', this).data('target');
    $('.'+lbl).show().siblings('label').hide();
});
```

Comment: i trying  your code its showing two value same time.  both  function default value 0.its showing both value